# From MYSQL SELECT to a MYSQL VIEW

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

I don't know how to make this.

---

Background:

Profiles -> table with user profiles

Score -> table with users' score (One user can have multiple scores) (This table has a created_at field to know when I introduce the new score)

Imagine that score table save klout score data.

---

How do convert this query to a view?

```
SELECT  t1.id, 
    t1.name, 
    t1.screen_name, 
    t1.description, 
    t1.url, 
    t1.statuses_count, 
    t1.followers_count, 
    t1.friends_count, 
    t1.listed_count, 
    t1.favourites_count, 
    t1.utc_offset, 
    t1.time_zone, 
    t1.verified, 
    t1.lang, 
    t1.profile_image_url, 
    t1.geo_enabled, 
    t1.location, 
    t1.lat, 
    t1.lng, 
    t1.created_at, 
    t3.score, 
    t3.delta, 
    t3.detail
        FROM profiles t1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT t2.user_id, t2.score, t2.delta, t2.detail
                                                    FROM scores t2
                                                    ORDER BY t2.created_at DESC) 
                AS t3 ON t3.user_id = t1.id
        GROUP BY t1.id
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem `VIEW` cannot contain `subquery`, the subquery in your query can be directly join on the table since you haven't perform any aggregation.

```
CREATE VIEW viewName
AS
SELECT  t1.id, 
        t1.name, 
        t1.screen_name, 
        t1.description, 
        t1.url, 
        t1.statuses_count, 
        t1.followers_count, 
        t1.friends_count, 
        t1.listed_count, 
        t1.favourites_count, 
        t1.utc_offset, 
        t1.time_zone, 
        t1.verified, 
        t1.lang, 
        t1.profile_image_url, 
        t1.geo_enabled, 
        t1.location, 
        t1.lat, 
        t1.lng, 
        t1.created_at, 
        t3.score, 
        t3.delta, 
        t3.detail
FROM    profiles t1 
        LEFT JOIN scores t3
            ON t3.user_id = t1.id
-- GROUP BY t1.id
```

I can't get why you have a `GROUP BY` clause in your query.

Comment: Background:

Profiles -> table with user profiles

Score -> table with users' score (One user can have multiple scores) (This table has a created_at field to know when i introduce the new score)

Imagine that score table save klout score data.

Comment: I don't get the group by either. Usually group by's are only considered if there is an aggregation. For ex: a.name, a.id, sum(a.amt_paid) from table a group by a.name, a.id = summed amt paid for each unique name and id combination....there is no reason in the above to use the group by or the select on the left join, it is just going to make your query take forever to compute, and your query is default grouped by ID as it is the first element in your query

Answer (score 0):

You can split your code into 2 views

View 1:

```
CREATE VIEW step1

AS

SELECT t2.user_id, t2.score, t2.delta, t2.detail
FROM scores t2
ORDER BY t2.created_at DESC
```

View 2:

```
CREATE VIEW step2

AS

SELECT  t1.id, 
                t1.name, 
                t1.screen_name, 
                t1.description, 
                t1.url, 
                t1.statuses_count, 
                t1.followers_count, 
                t1.friends_count, 
                t1.listed_count, 
                t1.favourites_count, 
                t1.utc_offset, 
                t1.time_zone, 
                t1.verified, 
                t1.lang, 
                t1.profile_image_url, 
                t1.geo_enabled, 
                t1.location, 
                t1.lat, 
                t1.lng, 
                t1.created_at, 
                t3.score, 
                t3.delta, 
                t3.detail
FROM profiles t1 
     LEFT JOIN step1 AS t3 ON t3.user_id = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

I am not sure why you are grouping by t1.id, but maybe there's something in your data that I don't know about